# SQL Server in asp Report

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am running into a problem where I am needing to accomplish something, but have never had experience with it before. I am currently running an asp site and using SQL Server for the database. I have a report that I takes the querysting from the filters page and then gives the information based on the querstring. It is an intake report, so there should only be a single line item and record per client hat appears in the report. On the report it gives information such as the date of first contact, and when the client started services with us. I am adding a new field to the report called services. It is possible and more common that there are many services to one client. Here is what I am needing to accomplish. I need for each service for that client to be listed in a single data cell on the report, without displaying multiple line items for that client. I was thinking that the answer may be accomplished by using BOF and EOF, but I am not sure how to take a stab at it. Here is the RecordSet that is already on the report, which contains every field with the exception of the new field, because I have tried to create a new RecordSet for that Field. Below are images that will hopefully give the idea of what I want to accomplish. Thank you so much for your input!

This image is what It looks like now... I want to put all of the services that show for aa aa to be in a single data cell rather than creating a new line for each service provided. 
[Image of what It looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3edc.png)

This is an image I created in photoshop to show what I am really wanting it to look like.
[This is a rough idea of What I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQcDY.png)

Here is the code so far.

```
<%
Dim rsClients
Dim rsClients_numRows

Set rsClients = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsClients.ActiveConnection = MM_ims_db_STRING
rsClients.Source = "SELECT" _
& " vClients.ClientID" _
& ", vClients.AgencyID" _
& ", vClients.OfficeID" _
& ", vClients.OfficeName" _
& ", vClients.LastName" _
& ", vClients.FirstName" _
& ", vClients.ClientTeamName" _
& ", vClients.EnrolledDate" _
& ", vClients.Agency" _
& ", ReferralSources.ReferralSourceID" _
& ", ReferralSourceText" _
& ", ReferralTypeID" _
& ", ReferralSources.ReferralSource" _
& ", ReferralType" _
& ", vClients.DataEntryDate" _
& ", vClients.DataEntryDays" _
& ", ReferralStaffID" _
& ", ReferralStaffName" _
& ", DataEntryStaffID" _
& ", Staff_1.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_1.LastName AS DataEntryStaffName" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stContactStaffID" _
& ", Staff.FirstName + ' ' + Staff.LastName AS Intake1stContactStaffName" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stContactAssignedDate" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stContactCompletedDate" _
& ",vClients. Intake1stScheduledStaffID" _
& ", Staff_2.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_2.LastName AS Intake1stScheduledStaffName" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stScheduledAssignedDate" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stScheduledCompletedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeAssessorStaffID" _
& ", Staff_3.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_3.LastName AS IntakeAssessorStaffName" _
& ", vClients.IntakeAssessorAssignedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeAssessorCompletedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeReviewerStaffID" _
& ", Staff_4.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_4.LastName AS IntakeReviewerStaffName" _
& ", vClients.IntakeReviewerAssignedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeReviewerCompletedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeServicesStaffID" _
& ", Staff_5.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_5.LastName AS IntakeServicesStaffName" _
& ", vClients.IntakeServicesAssignedDate" _
& ", vClients.IntakeServicesCompletedDate" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stContactAssignedDays" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stContactCompletedDays" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stScheduledAssignedDays" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stScheduledCompletedDays" _
& ", vClients.IntakeAssessorAssignedDays" _
& ", vClients.IntakeAssessorCompletedDays" _
& ", vClients.IntakeReviewerAssignedDays" _
& ", vClients.IntakeReviewerCompletedDays" _
& ", vClients.IntakeServicesAssignedDays" _
& ", IntakeServicesCompletedDays" _
& ", Staff_6.FirstName + ' ' + Staff_6.LastName AS Intake1stSessionStaffName" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stSessionDate" _
& ", vClients.Intake1stSessionDays" _
& ", vClientServices.PurposeCodeID" _
& ", vClientServices.PurposeType" _
& ", vClientServices.PurposeCode" _
& ", vClientServices.PurposeDescription" _
& ", vClients.Status" _
& " FROM vClients" _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff ON vClients.Intake1stContactStaffID = Staff.StaffID " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vClientServices ON vClientServices.ClientID = vClients.ClientID " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ReferralSources ON vClients.ReferralSourceID = ReferralSources.ReferralSourceID" _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_1 ON Staff_1.StaffID = vClients.DataEntryStaffID " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_2 ON Staff_2.StaffID = vClients.Intake1stScheduledStaffID" _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_3 ON Staff_3.StaffID = vClients.IntakeAssessorStaffID  " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_4 ON Staff_4.StaffID = vClients.IntakeReviewerStaffID  " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_5 ON Staff_5.StaffID = vClients.IntakeServicesStaffID  " _
& " LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Staff AS Staff_6 ON Staff_6.StaffID = vClients.Intake1stSessionStaffID  " _
& rsClients__sqlFrom _
& " WHERE " & rsClients__sqlFilter _
& " ORDER BY " & rsClients__sqlSortBy & ""
rsClients.CursorType = 0
rsClients.CursorLocation = 2
rsClients.LockType = 1
rsClients.Open()

rsClients_numRows = 0
%>





 <% If Not rsClients.EOF And Not rsClients.BOF Then %>
          <% 
    While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsClients.EOF)) 
    %>
            <tr class="gridItem">
              <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/clientsDetails.asp?ClientID=<%=rsClients.Fields.Item("ClientID").Value%>"><img src='/images/details16x16.gif' border='0' title='Client Details' /></a></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=rsClients.Fields.Item("FirstName").Value & " " & rsClients.Fields.Item("LastName").Value%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Status").Value)%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("OfficeName").Value)%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("ClientTeamName").Value)%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("PurposeType").Value & " - " & rsClients.Fields.Item("PurposeDescription").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("EnrolledDate").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("ReferralType").Value)%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("ReferralSource").Value)%></td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("ReferralSourceText").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("ReferralStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("DataEntryStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><% If Not IsNull(rsClients.Fields.Item("DataEntryDate").Value) Then Response.Write(FormatDateTime(rsClients.Fields.Item("DataEntryDate").Value,vbShortDate)) End If %></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("DataEntryDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stContactStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stContactAssignedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stContactAssignedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stContactCompletedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stContactCompletedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stScheduledStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stScheduledAssignedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stScheduledAssignedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stScheduledCompletedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stScheduledCompletedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeAssessorStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeAssessorAssignedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeAssessorAssignedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeAssessorCompletedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeAssessorCompletedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeReviewerStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeReviewerAssignedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeReviewerAssignedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeReviewerCompletedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeReviewerCompletedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeServicesStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeServicesAssignedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeServicesAssignedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeServicesCompletedDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("IntakeServicesCompletedDays").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;</td>
              <td nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stSessionStaffName").Value)%></td>
              <td><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stSessionDate").Value)%></td>
              <td align="center"><%=(rsClients.Fields.Item("Intake1stSessionDays").Value)%></td>
            </tr>
            <% 
        Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
        Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
        rsClients.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a hold variable(s) for the column(s) you want to hinge on. Here would be some pseudo code that should get you down the right path:

```
    strClientIdHold = ""

    While  NumRows <> 0 And Not EOF
        If strClientIdHold <> rs("ClientId") Then
            <td>rs("ClientId")</td>
            <td>second column</td>
            <td>third column</td>
            <td>rs("Services")</td>
            <td>fifth column</td>
            <td>...</td>

            strClientId = rs("ClientId")
        Else
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>rs("Services")</td>
            <td colspan="8"></td>
        End If

        Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
        Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
        rsClients.MoveNext()
    Wend
```

If you wanted you could do other checks too to see if other columns change... i.e. Can one client Id have more than one office or team that you'll want to pivot on and show that column too? You would then just have another hold variable for that as well.

I hope this helps.